# Searching Channels with YouTube API returns incorrect results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, discord, discord.py, youtube-data-api

Using this code allows me to search for YouTube channels and return their statistics; for some reason, however, only about half the channels return any results.

For example, if I use this [link to test the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22statistics%22%5D%2C%22forUsername%22%3A%22Animal%20Planet%22%7D), you can see that I searched for `Animal Planet`, and that yields no results. However, if we go to YouTube's website and search for the same thing, we get the channel as needed.

Why does this happen and how can this be fixed?

This is the code I used:

```
    @commands.command()
    async def yt_test(self, ctx, *, search):
        api_key = '...'
        youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)
        request = youtube.channels().list(
            part="snippet,statistics",
            forUsername=search,
            maxResults=1
        )
        response = request.execute()
        try:
            for item in response['items']:
                link = item['id']
                thumb_image = item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']
                views = "{:,}".format(int(item['statistics']['viewCount']))
                subs = "{:,}".format(int(item['statistics']['subscriberCount']))
                vidCount = "{:,}".format(int(item['statistics']['videoCount']))
        except:
            Notfound = discord.Embed(description= "Sorry, but this Channel was not located, check spelling" , color=0xfc0328)
            await ctx.send(embed=Notfound)
    
        finalresult = discord.Embed(title = search, url='https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + link, 
        description= '**Statistics**\nViews: ' + views + '\nSubscribers: ' + subs + "\nVideos: " + vidCount, color=0x00ff00)
        finalresult.set_thumbnail(url = thumb_image)
        await ctx.send(embed=finalresult)
        print(f"{ctx.author} looked up the profile of {search} --- in #{ctx.guild.name}")
```

Comment: still trying to figure out what you wrote, Im new to this not to mention I'm 16

Comment: No problem; just post comments down below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to acknowledge that invoking the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, by passing to it the parameter [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername), is by no means the same thing as going to the YouTube's Web UI for to apply a manual search. For these things to come to light, do bear with me for a little while...

According to the official docs, the `Channels.list` endpoint invoked with `forUsername=...` produces the meta-data associated to the channel of which username is given as argument to the parameter `forUsername`:

> `forUsername` (string)
>
> The `forUsername` parameter specifies a YouTube username, thereby requesting the channel associated with that username.

According to [an official Google staff post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130#comment5) from 2013-07-11, *it's not a requisite that every channel have attached an username*. Hence, is perfectly possible for `Channels.list` endpoint to return no channel at all, if the argument of `forUsername` does not represent a YouTube username.

If you use one of my public (MIT licensed) Python 3 script -- [`youtube-search.py`](https://gist.github.com/stvar/f57e9792c3dc49fab2690247d6ee74de) --, you'll see that it returns nothing for your queried username `Animal Planet`:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --user-name "Animal Planet"
youtube-search.py: error: user name "Animal Planet": no associated channel found
```

But if you invoke that script as follows:

```
$ python3 youtube-search.py --search-term "Animal Planet" --type channel
UCkEBDbzLyH-LbB2FgMoSMaQ: Animal Planet
UCuTSm59-_kap6J7Se-orUVA: Animal Planet Latinoamérica
UCpvajaPSWvFlyl83xvzs65A: animalplanet românia
UCgyOEJZJLPKclqrDyUkZ6Ag: Animal planet 1
UCypzlOdJyyOR2NhKv0o3zig: 動物星球頻道/ Animal Planet Taiwan
UCmMm-p51c14XJ1p294faCmA: Animal Planet Brasil
UCejVe2sNPjjvfCXg35q_EQQ: Animal Planet Videos
UClQLf_zw2A_nRaB45HWTbtA: Your Animal Planet
UChQEdt9dBiCkcCch6LyrjtA: Cute Animal Planet
UCRIS8Y1kfrFvFF_6vt6_3Cg: Animal Planet Videos
```

you'll see pretty much the same output as the YouTube's Web UI will show when queried for the same search term and filtered for `TYPE` being `Channel`.

[image: YouTube Web UI Screenshot]

Do note that your own results (the one obtained from `youtube-search.py` and the other provided by the YouTube Web UI) may very likely differ from the above ones; this is so because Google searches are tailored for the user that initiates the query.

The explanation behind the matching results sets obtained from `youtube-search.py` and YouTube Web UI is the following:

*The API endpoint that corresponds to YouTube's own search feature accessible via its Web UI is none other than [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)*.

Do convince yourself about this claim by reading the code of `youtube-search.py`: when invoking it with `--search-term "Animal Planet" --type channel`, that script executes the function `Service.search_term`:

```py
class Service:
    ...
    def search_term(self, term, type = None):
        resp = self.youtube.search().list(
            q = term,
            type = type,
            part = 'id,snippet',
            fields = 'items(id,snippet(title))',
            maxResults = self.max_results
        ).execute()
       ...
```

with `term` equal to the string `Animal Planet` and `type` equal to the string `channel`. Consequently, this script is calling for the `Search.list` endpoint, passing to it the parameters [`q`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) and [`type`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) as mentioned.

Comment: What would the code look like to return the channel id as you did in your example

Comment: `Service.search_term` invokes the `Search.list` endpoint with parameter `fields = 'items(id,snippet(title))'` too; hence, the endpoint returns back only channel IDs and titles. Do read down below the implementation of `Service.search_term` for to see how to collect the IDs.

Comment: If you'll hardwire `type = 'channel'` in your code, then the loop `for item in items:` will simply do `res.append(item['id']['channelId'])`, having `res` initialized simply as `res = []` before entering the `for` loop.

Comment: What I am thinking is having your code return the channel id through the `Animal Planet` search example. Then I will be put that ID which you provide into the youtube API to then return me a link

Comment: Note that `Search.list` may well return several channel ID (as `youtube-search.py` does above).

Comment: things are I don't understand how I can run your code, never really seen anything like it before and I can't find anything online to help em

Comment: To what kind of links are your referring when you say *put that ID ... into the youtube API to then return me a link*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223186/discussion-between-stvar-and-dan-a).

Comment: I ran into a problem when I tried modifying the code, I am unable to post the channel name into the output, it instead puts in the search that the user put in. Example: User input is "Tom Scoot" the program prints out "Tom Scoot" as the name when in reality it is, "Tom Scott"